# Looking for a fantasy book about two kids that get transported to another world

Tags: story-identification, books

It's a book about two kids that get transported to this fantasy world. The people there want to make one of them ruler of one of the countries and the other is hunted down. It's got fantasy and fairy tale elements also in it.

Comment: Can you tell us anything else about the book?  When did you read it?  Based on that, a rough guess at when it might have been written?  Did it have any particular cover art that was notable, or any character names or other details you can provide?

Comment: Not a perfect match, but perhaps [The Key to Rondo?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rondo_(series))

Answer (score 2):

The name of the book is Farworld, I've been looking for it too and I just found it. 
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3223890-water-keep

Comment: Please explain why you think this is the answer. What elements of *Farworld* match the description in the question?

Answer (score 1):

[Northern Lights - Phillip Pullman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Lights_%28novel%29)?

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  We appreciate your answer, but could you at least provide a bit of a synopsis of the story so the OP has a chance to verify whether or not this is actually the story they are seeking?  Thanks

Comment: This one seems doubtful to me. Incidentally, this is *The Golden Compass* in the United States.